How to filter a Polars dataframe into two parts: rows that match a condition, and rows that do not?
I can split the dataframe df into two parts like so:
    predicate = pl.col("a").gt(pl.col("b"))
    dfx = df.filter(predicate)
    dfy = df.filter(~predicate)

This is wasteful, because we do not want/need to go through df twice in order to produce dfx and dfy. Is there a better method?

There's partition_by (https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.partition_by.html) but it only accepts existing columns, so you'll have to add a column for the predicate, then partition, then drop it, which doesn't seem to be worth it.

@Dogbert I think that might be good enough. From what I understand, adding a column is cheap (after all, a DataFrame is just a collection of series, and we can remove and add series cheaply (although creating a series might not be cheap, but in this case, it would be cheap because we are only calculating the predicate once, instead of twice))?

You can group_by any expression, not just existing columns, so you can group_by on the predicate. Then you can just iterate through the GroupBy object.
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"a": np.random.randint(5, size=10), "b": np.random.randint(2, size=10)},
)

for (key, group) in df.group_by(pl.col("a") > pl.col("b")):
    print(f"{key=}")
    print(group)
    print()

key=(True,)
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 0   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘

key=(False,)
shape: (7, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 0   ┆ 0   │
│ 0   ┆ 1   │
│ 0   ┆ 0   │
│ 0   ┆ 1   │
│ 0   ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘


You can use with_columns to add your predicate, then partition_by with the include_key set to False to remove that column. Also, you need to sort by that column and use maintain_order to get the results reliably where you want them to be.
All together you can do
dfx, dfy = (
    df
    .with_columns(_z=pl.col("a").gt(2))
    .sort('_z')
    .partition_by('_z',maintain_order=True, include_key=False)
)

